# tflite_convert ValueError Unknown layer BatchNorm

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

We are using 
Tensorflow 1.14
Keras 2.1.2
GPU: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.86
for custom object detection using Mask-RCNN from this repo https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN.
Now we trained a model successfully and its detecting objects on our desktop. Now, we want to generate `tflite` for mobile usage where we are facing below mentioned error:

```
ValueError: Unknown layer BatchNorm
```

Please note that we have created weights and keras model `.h5` with different scripts

We have tried following code to convert keras model to tflite

```
import tensorflow as tf
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file( 'Save-Model8.h5')
tfmodel = converter.convert()
open ("model.tflite", "wb") .write(tfmodel)
```

Comment: Have u checked operators compatibility here?https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_compatibility